# How to use "src_sqlite" of dplyr on R

Tags: r, dplyr

Here is the quote from the article named "Taming PITCHf/x Data with XML2R and pitchRx" written by Carson Sievert:

```
library(dplyr)
my_db <- src_sqlite("GamedayDB.sqlite3", create = TRUE)
# Collect and store all PITCHf/x data from 2008 to 2013
scrape(start = "2008-01-01", end = "2014-01-01",
suffix = "inning/inning_all.xml", connect = my_db$con)
```

[Source](https://pitchrx.cpsievert.me/RJwrapper.pdf)

However, even after installing the dplyr package, I cannot use the function "src_sqlite" as it says

> Failed to load extension

Please advise how I can make the above code work.

Comment: Are you sure you mean `src_sqlite` and not `src_sql`? I don't think `src_sqlite` comes from dplyr. What does `environment(src_sqlite)` return?

Comment: First of all, I'm using `src_sqlite` in accordance with the journal, the link to which is in the original post. `environment(src_sqlite)` returned `<environment: namespace:dplyr>`. I tried `src_sql` but it said `Error: could not find function sqc_sql` Is there any problem with dplyr package?